# Strange RegionDifference output on simple example

Tags: plotting, regions

Why is the output so irregular in the following simple example?

```
Region[RegionDifference[
       Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {5, 1}], 
       RegionUnion[Disk[{0.5, 0}, 0.25], Disk[{3.5, 0}, 0.25]]
]]
```

[image]

I'm using MMA 12.1 on Windows.

Comment: What's displayed is a quick representation of the region.  To get a high quality plot, use `RegionPlot` or `DiscretizeRegion`.

Answer (score 6):

This irregularity only appears in the visualization from the `Region` wrapper. Under the hood the region is still exactly intact:

```
reg = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {5, 1}], 
  RegionUnion[Disk[{0.5, 0}, 0.25], Disk[{3.5, 0}, 0.25]]];

Area[Rationalize[reg]]
```

> ```
> 14 - π/8
> ```

Most likely `Region` is using a general method like [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) to visualize this region:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, Method -> "MarchingSquares"]
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, more or less: `Trace[
 MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &[reg],
 _BoundaryDiscretizeRegion,
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]`

Answer (score 6):

```
DiscretizeRegion[#
   , AccuracyGoal -> 3
   , PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
   (*,Method\[Rule]"Continuation"*)
   ] &@RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {5, 1}], 
  RegionUnion[Disk[{0.5, 0}, 0.25], Disk[{3.5, 0}, 0.25]]]
```

---

- `AccuracyGoal` can be set to 2 to get good enough circles. A value such as 10 locks my computer up but that could be due to many reasons.
- Method->"Continuation" (without the accuracy goal) also delivers good results for this case while maintaining good response time.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A one more way is as follows.

```
RegionPlot[RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {5, 1}], 
RegionUnion[Disk[{0.5, 0}, 0.25], Disk[{3.5, 0}, 0.25]]], AspectRatio -> 2/7]
```

[image]